# using a method trait in a traitsui factory

Tags: enthought, traits, traitsui

I am trying to figure out how `Method` traits work and if I can use one in a factory defined in a traits View object in order to have dynamic values passed to the factory.

Here is what I mean, a minimal test case which works except for the factory behavior (it runs, but using the factory will cause a crash):

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Method, Str, List, Instance, method, Int, Any
from traitsui.api import View, Item, TableEditor, ObjectColumn, TextEditor

class Dog(HasTraits):
    name = Str('Fido')
    value = Int(5)

class DogTable(HasTraits):

    def factory(self):
        return Dog(value=self.current_user_value)    

    dog_factory = Method(factory)

    dogs = List(Instance(Dog))
    current_user_value = Int(3)

    def _dogs_default(self):
        return [
            Dog(name='Joe', value=6),
            Dog(name='Ted', value=2),
        ]

    traits_view = View(
        Item('dogs',
            editor=TableEditor( columns =
                [
                ObjectColumn(label='name', editor=TextEditor(), name='name'),
                ObjectColumn(label='value', editor=TextEditor(), name='value'),
                ],
               row_factory = dog_factory,
            )
        ),
        Item('current_user_value'),
        height=300, width=300,
    )

DogTable().configure_traits()
```

So what I am trying to do here is set up the factory so that the user can add new items to the table which contain as an initial `value` whatever value is currently specified by the user in the GUI.

Is there some way to do this? I thought that using a `Method` trait would resolve this problem by referring to the bound method and allow me to actually call the bound method in this instance, but it seems like `Method`'s semantics are no different from `Callable`. And I can't figure out any way to supply arguments to the factory dynamically, other possibly than by hacky use of `eval` or global variables (`factory_row_args` rejects dynamic arguments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I was very tired, today I thought of an obvious way to do it:

```
def dog_factory(self):
    return Dog(value=self.current_user_value)

def view_getter(self):
    return  View(
        Item('dogs',
            editor=TableEditor( columns =
                [
                ObjectColumn(label='name', editor=TextEditor(), name='name'),
                ObjectColumn(label='value', editor=TextEditor(), name='value'),
                ],  
               row_factory = self.dog_factory
            )
        ),
        Item('current_user_value'),
        height=300, width=300,
    )

def configure_traits(self):
    super(DogTable, self).configure_traits(view=self.view_getter())
```